# Subtracting the difference between 2 dates Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime

I want to write piece of code that returns the number of days hours minutes that are differ between values of `backtest_results` and `realtime_test`. So I want to perform `2022-01-24 10:05:00 - 2022-01-30 14:09:03, 2022-01-27 01:54:00 - 2022-02-02 09:34:06`,

```
backtest_results[0] - realtime_test[0]
backtest_results[1] - realtime_test[1]
...
```

How would I be able top code the wanted code below.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy

backtest_results = pd.to_datetime(['2022-01-24 10:05:00', '2022-01-27 01:54:00', 
                     '2022-01-30 19:08:00','2022-02-02 14:32:00',
                     '2022-02-10 02:58:00', '2022-02-10 14:01:00',
                     '2022-02-11 00:25:00' '2022-02-16 13:49:00'])
    
realtime_test = pd.to_datetime([
                '2022-01-30 14:09:03', '2022-02-02 09:34:06',
                '2022-02-08 07:37:03', '2022-02-09 22:07:02',
                '2022-02-10 09:02:03', '2022-02-10 19:32:25',
                '2022-02-12 16:42:03', '2022-02-15 23:19:03'])
result = backtest_results - realtime_test
```

Comment: Your code is correct, you just did not put a comma in the value of `backtest_results`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma in `backtest_results` in the last row:

```
backtest_results = pd.to_datetime(['2022-01-24 10:05:00', '2022-01-27 01:54:00', 
                     '2022-01-30 19:08:00','2022-02-02 14:32:00',
                     '2022-02-10 02:58:00', '2022-02-10 14:01:00',
                     '2022-02-11 00:25:00', '2022-02-16 13:49:00'])
                                          ^^ here
```

Then, you can simply subtract one from the other.

If you want the raw difference:

```
>>> backtest_results - realtime_test
TimedeltaIndex(['-7 days +19:55:57', '-7 days +16:19:54', '-9 days +11:30:57',
                '-8 days +16:24:58', '-1 days +17:55:57', '-1 days +18:28:35',
                '-2 days +07:42:57',   '0 days 14:29:57'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

If you want to get the difference is days:

```
>>> (backtest_results - realtime_test).astype('timedelta64[D]')
Float64Index([-7.0, -7.0, -9.0, -8.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0], dtype='float64')
```

If you want the difference in hours:

```
>>> (backtest_results - realtime_test).astype('timedelta64[h]')
Float64Index([-149.0, -152.0, -205.0, -176.0, -7.0, -6.0, -41.0, 14.0], dtype='float64')
```

If you want the difference in minutes:

```
>>> (backtest_results - realtime_test).astype('timedelta64[m]')
Float64Index([-8885.0, -9101.0, -12270.0, -10536.0, -365.0, -332.0, -2418.0, 869.0], dtype='float64')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['diff'] = df.EndDate - df.StartDtate
df.diff = df.diff / np.timedelta64(1. 'D')
```

‘D’ for day, ‘W’ for weeks, ‘M’ for month, ‘Y’ for year